# Fetch data from server swiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swiftui

I need to fetch data before view loads and display the data in a button text.

```
Locations.swift

class GetLocations :ObservableObject{

 @Published var arrLocations = NSArray()
 
   func getLocNames(Action:String, Id: String, completion: @escaping (NSArray) -> Void){

       //fetch data from server
     let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  
    in 
if let response = response {
                    print(response)
                }
 if let data = data {
                    let parseResult: NSDictionary!
                    do {
                        parseResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
self.arrLocations = (parseResult.value(forKey: "InfoList"))as! NSArray 
                    }catch {
                       print(error)
                   }
                }
            }.resume()
           
           return self.arrLocations
    }
}
```

Now I called the above function in another swiftUI file

```
GetLocationData.swift
```

```
    import SwiftUI
    struct GetLocationData: View {
     @State var arrloc = NSArray()
     init() {
                let g = GetLocations()
                g.getLocNames(Action: "US", Id: "ba6fcd92-3d1e-4fb6-b135-0c47ea1815cd"){locationsarray in
                    self.arrloc = locationsarray
       }
}
    var body: some View {
      VStack(spacing: 20){
        Button(action: {},
         label: {
                 Text("Select Menu"). //Here I need to assign the locationsarray I got from server and assign the valueof key to it (In obj-C we have [array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Name"]].
 I couldnt find the equivalent of it in swift

                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 500)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.clear)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
                .overlay(
                          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                           .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                                )

        })
      }
    }
```

Error in init() : `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`
How can I get it solved and get data before the view loads and assign the data to button text ?

Comment: Your `getLocNames` and `getLocationsByAppId` don't match names. As well as that, in `getLocNames` you are returning a value, where as `getLocationsByAppId` appears to be using a closure instead. These aren't the same methods.

Comment: First, don't use `NS...` classes in Swift. Use swift native types.  Second, move your data into a model object. Separation of model and view is a very important concept in SwiftUI. Use `@Published` for the array and you will initially have an empty array and the view will be automatically redrawn once the array is populated.

Comment: @George I edited my code. Actually I changed the names of methods , so while doing so in posting in SO names dint match.

Comment: @Paulw11  Published is already used . Plz chk my code

Comment: your init() is missing a "}", that is your problem.

Comment: @Honey The definition of `getLocNames` still uses a `return` in the code. If you wish to return, since it doesn't appear to be asynchronous, do that instead of a completion handler-style approach. If it must be a closure, you will have to do this in `onAppear` instead since you don't know how long it will take `getLocNames` to run.

Comment: @workingdog That shouldn't give the above error message

Comment: fix the code and let us know if that works.

Comment: @George I used URLSession to get data  from server and I need that data (0th element with "Name" key to be as button text . I edited my code

Comment: Then you shouldn't have an `@State` array. You should have an instance of `GetLocations` as a simple property. Call `getLocNames` in init or in a `.onAppear` and use the `arrLocations` property from the `GetLocations` object in your view. You don't need a completion handler to be passed to `getLocNames` and you can't `return` from an asynchronous function (you don't need to anyway)

Comment: @Paulw11 Can u plz post ur code in answer

Comment: @Paulw11 I did the way u said , now it gives me another error "Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'NSArray' conform to 'View'" and  "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'. I modified to code  at the rate ObservedObject  var getapps: GetLocations = GetLocations()  var body: some View {VStack(spacing: 20){getapps. getLocNames(Action: "US", Id: "")print(getapps. arrloc)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to clear up is the separation between your model and your view.

`GetLocations` is your model class.  It is an `ObservableObject` and it has an `@Published` array of your location names.  There is no need for the `@State` array.  You should refer to an instance of your model object directly.

Since the model object will update its own `arrLocations` property, there is also no need to pass a completion handler to `getLocNames` - This is the cause of your error.  You are trying to mutate `self` - your view struct - in a closure from its own initialiser. This is not possible as structs are immutable.

While we are looking at your model object, let's get rid of the use of `NSArray` (You should always use properly typed arrays in Swift) and the old-style `JSONSerialization` and use `Codable`.  I assume that the array you are after is an array of some struct, that has at least a `Name` property which is a string - If you want other properties you need to add those to the struct.  We'll also add `codingKeys` to map the upper-case property names to camel case.

```
struct LocationResponse {
    let infoList: [LocationInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case infoList = "InfoList"
    }
}

struct LocationInfo {
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
    }
}

class GetLocations: ObservableObject{

 @Published var arrLocations = [String]()
 
   func getLocNames(Action:String, Id: String {

       //fetch data from server
       let session = URLSession.shared
       session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in 
           if let response = response {
                    print(response)
           }

           if let data = data {
               do {
                   let locationResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocationResponse.self, from: data)
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.arrLocations = locationResponse.infoList
                   }
               } catch {
                   print("JSON decoding error: \(error)")
               }
           }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Now, you need to pass an instance of your model object to your view.  I suggest using the environment.  Add the instance to your environment by using the `.environmentObject` view modifier where you create your `GetLocationData` view

```
GetLocationData().environmentObject(GetLocations())
```

Then you can use it in your content view. Rather than using `init`, I suggest you use `.onAppear` to fetch the locations.

I couldn't quite follow what you wanted to do with the buttons, so I have replaced that code with a simple list of the location names - You should be able to work from this

```
struct GetLocationData: View {
    @EnvironmentObject: getLocations: GetLocations
      
    var body: some View {
      VStack(spacing: 20){
          ForEach(getLocations.infoList, id: \.self) { location in
              Text(location.name)
          }
      }.onAppear {
          self.getLocations.getLocNames(Action: "US", Id: "ba6fcd92-3d1e-4fb6-b135-0c47ea1815cd")
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the problem. You are trying to run an asynchronous function in the `init`, setting the result of that to a property. The problem is that since `GetLocationData` hasn't been instantiated yet, there is no instance of `self` to use.

Here is a simplified example of the **problem**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var completed = false

    init() {
        someAsyncronousTask { newCompleted in // <- Error here
            completed = newCompleted
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Completed: \(completed ? "yes" : "no")")
    }

    private func someAsyncronousTask(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            // Waited 3 seconds to simulate something like URLSession request
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives us the error, like you had:

> Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

To fix this, just run this code in the `onAppear` of the view.

Fixed example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var completed = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Completed: \(completed ? "yes" : "no")")
            .onAppear {
                someAsyncronousTask { newCompleted in
                    completed = newCompleted
                }
            }
    }

    private func someAsyncronousTask(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            // Waited 3 seconds to simulate something like URLSession request
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously needs to be converted into your code, but I hope this gives you the idea because of the simplified code.

The end result should look something like this:

```
struct GetLocationData: View {
    @State var arrloc = NSArray()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Button(action: {},
                   label: {
                Text("Select Menu"). //Here I need to assign the locationsarray I got from server and assign the valueof key to it (In obj-C we have [array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Name"]].
                I couldnt find the equivalent of it in swift

                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 500)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                    )

            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            let g = GetLocations()
            g.getLocNames(Action: "US", Id: "ba6fcd92-3d1e-4fb6-b135-0c47ea1815cd"){locationsarray in
                self.arrloc = locationsarray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: you should use `Array` rather than `NSArray`.*

Comment: But I dont want to wait for 3 sec.. May b I dont need async request here as I want t o display the data in viewload

Comment: @Honey No that's not the point. The 3 seconds is just to show that something might happen after some time, just like your `URLSession`. Your `URLSession` isn't instant - which is why it has a closure rather than a return type.

Comment: @Honey Added code of what yours should look like